# XSLT - transform a table structure to FO

Tags: xslt, xsl-fo

I would like to create a transformation for the INPUT to get the OUTPUT. I was trying various transformations but it didn't work. I tried to put `<xsl:for-each>` between `<fo:table-body>` and `<fo:table-row>` elements but I got an error that a child element is missing (it was the `<fo:table-row>`). Any help would be appreciated.

`INPUT`

```
<table>
<tgroup>
    <thead>
        <row>
            <entry>A</entry>
            <entry>B</entry>
        </row>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <row>
            <entry>a1</entry>
            <entry>a2</entry>
        </row>
        <row>
            <entry>b1</entry>
            <entry>b2</entry>
        </row>
    </tbody>
</tgroup>
</table>
```

`OUTPUT`

```
<fo:table>
    <fo:table-body>
        <fo:table-row font-weight="bold">
            <fo:table-cell>
                <fo:block>A</fo:block>
            </fo:table-cell>
            <fo:table-cell>
                <fo:block>B</fo:block>
            </fo:table-cell>
        </fo:table-row>
        <fo:table-row>
            <fo:table-cell>
                <fo:block>a1</fo:block>
            </fo:table-cell>
            <fo:table-cell>
                <fo:block>a2</fo:block>
            </fo:table-cell>
        </fo:table-row>
        <fo:table-row>
            <fo:table-cell>
                <fo:block>b1</fo:block>
            </fo:table-cell>
            <fo:table-cell>
                <fo:block>b2</fo:block>
            </fo:table-cell>
        </fo:table-row>
    </fo:table-body>
</fo:table>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a little hard from a sample to figure out how to advise on for-each error, because I think it's xpath related and there is no reference to it.

Here's an alternative solution, using apply-templates instead. (and also I think in this case it's better to use apply-templates then for-each):

```
<xsl:template match="table">
    <fo:table>
        <fo:table-body>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="tgroup/*/row"/>
        </fo:table-body>
    </fo:table>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="thead/row">
    <fo:table-row font-weight="bold">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="entry" />
    </fo:table-row>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="tbody/row">
    <fo:table-row>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="entry" />
    </fo:table-row>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="entry">
    <fo:table-cell>
        <fo:block><xsl:value-of select="."/></fo:block>
    </fo:table-cell>
</xsl:template>
```

Hope this helps.

P.S. If you need a help with for-each loop, can you post a sample of a code that you tried and it didn't work.

Comment: your solution looks very nice. I'll try it tomorrow and tell you the progress. Thank you for now

Comment: I've edited this answer by removing modes (hope you like my edit) +1 for right approach in building tables.